# Error “dereferencing pointer to incomplete type” when trying to write to a struct ip

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip, traceroute

I tried to write a short own traceroute program in C for Linux using raw sockets,
but when I compile I get the error message “dereferencing pointer to incomplete type” `struct ip`.

These are the headers I include:

```
#include <netinet/ip.h>         
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>        
#include <sys/socket.h>         
#include <stdlib.h>             
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
```

and then how I use the ip header

```
struct ip *myIpHeader = (struct ip*)buffr;
```

followed by a bunch of stuff...then:

```
myIpHeader->ip_v = 4;                           
myIpHeader->ip_hl = 5;                      
myIpHeader->ip_tos = 0;                                             
myIpHeader->ip_len = 20+8;                  
myIpHeader->ip_off = 0;                     
myIpHeader->ip_p = IPPROTO_ICMP;                
inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(myIpHeader->ip_dst)); 
inet_pton(AF_INET, ownip->h_name, &(myIpHeader->ip_src));
myIpHeader->ip_sum = 0;                      
myIpHeader->ip_id = htonl(12345);                    
myIpHeader->ip_ttl = ttl;
```

And then I use it for sending:

```
sendto(mysock, buffr, sizeof myIpHeader + sizeof myicmphead, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, sizeof cliAddr);
```

Comment: show complete struct definition and declaration, probably you have declared a nameless struct.

Comment: No, you cannot have a pointer to an anonymous struct type without the referenced type being complete, because you cannot reference an anonymous struct type from outside the scope of its definition.  Because it's, you know, anonymous.

Comment: But you *can* have a pointer to a named structure type whose definition is not in scope.  You can pass around such a pointer, but not dereference it.

Comment: Where do you think `struct ip` is defined — which header tells you about all the members of the structure?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Sulkily/crc) here can you find the complete code

Comment: @John Bollinger no anonymous or unnamed - nameless.

Comment: On a Mac, the header `<netinet/ip.h>` does seem to contain a `struct ip` — but that is not a header standardized by POSIX.  It's also there in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04).  So, it appears that when you do the dereferencing, you don't have the header included, or the contents of the header are 'invisible'.  Are you compiling with `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11`?  If the latter, you may need to enable POSIX (or GNU) definitions. Most easily fixed by using `-std=gnu11` instead; alternatively, maybe `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` or similar.

Comment: im using c11 thanks that fixed the error but now i got a segmentation fault-.-

Comment: @PeterJ, the adjective "nameless" does not appear anywhere in the standard.  If you're going to distinguish that from "anonymous" in some way that you think invalidates my point, then I'm afraid you'll need to clarify what you mean by it.  I re-assert that the problem has nothing to do with whether the structure type is declared with a tag (though it clearly is), but rather with whether the type definition is visible at some place where the pointer's use requires it to be.

Comment: A segmentation fault is a separate problem, requiring a wholly different solution.  Do you want me to create an answer from my comment, or will you just delete this?

Comment: well i guess i can just create an answer from your problem since it did help me even tho now i have another one

Comment: @JohnBollinger (and PeterJ): an 'anonymous struct' is a very specific construct, illustrated by: `struct Named { int i; struct { char c; double d; }; } var;` where the embedded structure has no name, so the elements `var.c` and `var.d` are mostly as if they were written as part of the main `struct Named` but are officially members of an anonymous struct.  As shown, the nested struct (or union) may not have a tag (§6.7.2.1¶13).  A structure type with no tag is a different creature.  There doesn't seem to be a specific name for it.

Comment: Yes, @JonathanLeffler, I know, but I was speaking more colloquially when I used the word "anonymous" earlier, as, I intended, a synonym for PeterJ's "nameless".  Colloquialism is always a bit risky around here, but I supposed that the balance of my comments would make the intended meaning clear.  I raised the standard later, when Peter insisted that his "nameless" meant something different from my (colloquial) "anonymous".

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I know what anonymous struct is, ans it is not something I had in mind.   I will show you a very common mistake: `struct {
 int a;
}a;


 struct a *b;

 b->a = 1;`

error: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct a' This is what I call `nameless` and I heard it hundred times here in the UK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a comment into an answer.*</sup>

On a Mac, the header `<netinet/ip.h>` does contain a `struct ip` — but that is not a header standardized by POSIX. It's also there in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). So, it appears that when you do the dereferencing, you don't have the header included, or the contents of the header are 'invisible'.

Are you compiling with `-std=gnu11` or `-std=c11`? If the latter, you probably need to enable POSIX (or GNU) definitions. That's most easily fixed by using `-std=gnu11` instead. Alternatively, use `-D_GNU_SOURCE` or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` or similar on the command line, or the equivalent `#define` in the source code.

For better or worse, I use a home-brew header `posixver.h`:

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: posixver.h,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.4 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2017/06/18 00:15:42 $
@(#)Purpose:        Request appropriate POSIX and X/Open Support
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 2010-2017
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2008 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700   /* SUS v4, POSIX 1003.1 2008/13 (POSIX 2008/13) */
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700   /* SUS v4, POSIX 1003.1 2008/13 (POSIX 2008/13) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

You may use that if you wish, with or without attribution.  You can find a version of the file at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.